# Как поменять содержимое ComboBox в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, combobox, битрикс24

Имеется раздел CRM, в нём Компании. При добавлении новой компании предлагается выбрать из выпадающего списка Тип.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как поменять содержимое этого списка в режиме администратора? Нажатие на кнопку "шестерёнки" не помогает.

Comment: хотя бы https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru прочитайте прежде чем задавать здесь вопросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Жмем Еще -> Настройки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего справочник -> Тип компании
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И там уже настраиваете

Comment: Огромная благодарность Вам!

Comment: А сами контролы в каком разделе ставятся на страницу? Скажем, текстовые поля и прочие?

Comment: @DmitryNikitin не очень понял вопрос, но внизу при создании компании есть пунктик `создать поле`, там создаете какое-хотите дополнительное